# Evaluate by means of the Cauchy Residue Theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have been asked to work out $\oint_{||=2π}\tan() dz$ by using the cauchy residue theorem (where the contour is positively oriented), I got that there are singularities at $-3\pi/2, -\pi/2, \pi/2$ and $3\pi/2$.
I know that this integral will be equal to: $2π  [Res(3π/2) + Res(π/2) + Res(−π/2) + Res(−3π/2)]$ by the cauchy residue theorem.
However then I am stuck at working out these residues, I looked at the solutions given to this and I got lost these are what is given:

$Res(π/2) = \lim_{→π/2}
( − π/2)\frac{\sin}{\cos}$

$= \lim_{→π/2}
( − π/2) \frac{\sin }
{\cos  − \cos(π/2)}$ (introducing \cos(π/2) = 0 judiciously)

$= \lim_{→π/2}\frac{\sin}{\frac{\cos −\cos(π/2)}{(−π/2)}}$

$= \lim_{→π/2}\frac{\sin}{(\cos)′}$ (by definition of the derivative)

$= \lim_{→π/2}\frac{\sin}{−\sin} = −1$.

However I cant follow the lines:

$= \lim_{→π/2}\frac{\sin}{\frac{\cos −\cos(π/2)}{(−π/2)}}$

$= \lim_{→π/2}\frac{\sin}{(\cos)′}$ (by definition of the derivative)

How is $\frac{\cos −\cos(π/2)}{(−π/2)}=(\cos z)'$?
The solution also only gave how to work out $\pi/2$ so i'm assuming this method would be equivalent for all the other residues and then just adding them together would give the answer as $−8πi$

Comment: This is the L'Hospital method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any derivative of a function e.g. of one variable can  be computed as follows:
$$\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$$
In your case $h=\pi/2-x$

Comment: Oh! and because $cosz$ is an even function when we get $f(z)'=lim_{h->0}\frac{f(\pi/2)-f(z)}{\pi/2-z}$ we can just switch over the signs on the top to get this result!

Comment: In your limit $h$ is wrong set, instead $z$ must tend to $\pi/2$ approximating from its left. And yes! You got it!

Answer (score 1):

This is showing the general method that the residue of $\frac{N}{D} = \frac{N}{D'}$ if it exists at that point.